# Telling Pyautogui to press a key for X seconds

Tags: python, pyautogui

I just started with python that's why I don't really know how to make certain things :)

I wanted to code that my character in a game moves from one spot to another other but the bot will do it forever because I set it in a loop (I want him to do it kind of all-day xd) it could be that it's the fault of the while loop but it didn't change anything when I tried.

Now I come to my question. I want him to move for a certain amount of like 2 seconds and then he should do the next thing. Is there a possibility to tell him that he should move for the amount of time I tell him or not? If yes, I would appreciate an answer :)

Have a nice day

[image: that's my code so far. I stopped because it didn't work so yeah]

Comment: Not to answer the question but just an advice, if you want to perform a lot of clicks or actions you should rather use win32con and win32api .

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you will need a different approach to solving this issue.

Also i don't advice using `.keyDown()` or `.keyUp()`. Instead, use `.press()`

Here's a code snippet to hold down a key for `5` seconds.

```
import time, pyautogui
    
start = time.time()
while time.time() - start < 5: #Hold Key for 5 Seconds
    pyautogui.press('d')
```

So you would need to change this flow to break out of the while loop as soon as it finds the `Fertilizer.png`
Like such:

```
import time, pyautogui
    
start = time.time()
while time.time() - start < 5: #Hold Key for 5 Seconds
    pyautogui.press('d')
        
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Fertilizer.png", confidence=1.0) == True:
        break
```

Comment: I rarely use the while loop because it's will affect your pc's performance by raising the CPU usage

Answer (score 0):

This should not create infinte loops, however you will have to rearrange the code to make it work for you.

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import asyncio
import time

async def wait4keystroke():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('YOUR KEY HERE') == True :
            return

async def main():
    while True :
        keystroke = asyncio.create_task(wait4keystroke())
        await keystroke
        pyautogui.keyDown(key='YOUR KEY HERE')
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.keyUp(key='YOUR KEY')

asyncio.run(main())`
```

I think you can just add your locate on screen condition where the keyboard.is_pressed condition is. Just add an and statement.

Answer (score -1):

here is a function that u can call that presses a given button for a given time

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep


def press_button(button_name, time_of_button_press):

    pyautogui.keyDown(button_name)
    sleep(time_of_button_press)
    pyautogui.keyUp(button_name)


button_name = "d"  # string
time_of_button_press = 1  # interger

press_button(button_name, time_of_button_press)
```

Comment: @SunAwtCanvas can you please explain what is wrong with my function?. It does exactly what the question was you give  it a button and a time the button needs to be pressed and it presses the given button for the given time